# Use multiple WHERE clauses to display result?

Tags: php, joomla, phpmyadmin, virtuemart

Good day,

I was hoping if anyone could help me. I'm using VirtueMart in Joomla. I've found a way to change the layout of the products which changes it to a list.

In VirtueMart you can create custom fields, which you can set the value to once you create a new product. Now, in this example, I have two custom fields:

1. Expiry Date
2. Batch Number

Now, the following piece of code will show the "customfield_value" from the correct table in the database WHERE "customfield_value" is equal to the "virtuemart_product_id".

```
 <?php //make a database connection and find the field record that contains the customfield string
 $db = JFactory::getDBO();
 $db->setQuery("SELECT customfield_value FROM jos_virtuemart_product_customfields WHERE virtuemart_product_id=".$product->virtuemart_product_id.";");
 $db->query();
 $result = $db->loadResult();
 echo ($result) ?>
```

That is all well and good. It must do that. However, there's one issue. When I copy this piece of code for the other "customfield_value" (Batch Number), it still shows only the first "customfield_value" (Expiry Date).

So now, it needs two conditions:

It needs to show the "customfield_value" WHERE the "customfield_ID" = "2" AND WHERE it is equal to the current "product_id".

I hope that makes sense.

I wrote some code below which I hope gives you an idea of what it needs to do. Can someone please help me review this code and see what I'm doing wrong:

```
 <?php //make a database connection and find the field record that contains the customfield string
 $db = JFactory::getDBO();
 $db->setQuery("SELECT customfield_value,customfield_id,virtuemart_product_id FROM jos_virtuemart_product_customfields WHERE virtuemart_product_id=".$product->virtuemart_product_id.";". AND "WHERE customfield_id=5");
 $db->query();
 $result = $db->loadResult();
 echo ($result) ?>
```

Thanks for reading and I hope someone can help me. I've been struggling with this and just can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use multiple `WHERE` keyword in condition just use `AND` to separate them in where also remove `;` from middle of the query

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT customfield_value,customfield_id,virtuemart_product_id 
FROM jos_virtuemart_product_customfields WHERE 
virtuemart_product_id=".$product->virtuemart_product_id." AND customfield_id=5");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man I will give it a try! I hope it works since I've tried messing around with the structure of the code but did not try this version.